# Redirect all pages from old site to my blog homepage in blogger

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Old and new site have different structure. Everything is differend.

I don't care about rankinks and SEO, but there are some backlinks that point there and I want to redirect them to the new site homepage. After some months I will delete the whole old site.

I just want a code for .htaccess that redirects any old site url  **to my new homepage** blogger site. I repaeat: To NEW HOMEPAGE, not in related urls.

The old site is hosted as user in my companys domain.

http://users.company.com/myOLDname/

the new one is in google blogger

http://myNEWname.blogspot.com/

Note: If you can help, please put this above url's in the code to better understand.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^users\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?myOLDname(?:/|$) https://myNEWname.blogspot.com/ [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file).

Comment: Seems that the rewrite module is not enabled, and this is not up to me. I don't think that the company administartor will change their policy. I have redirected all pages within every page with meta tags. There are about 30 pages. It' is done now. Thank you for your time arkascha.

Comment: An apache http server without rewriting module? I have never seen such thing before in a production environment. It is impossible to operate any application that way. Very strange...

Comment: I think I did not underestud correct the previous answer. I thougt that because my site is like a subdomain (user), I could not change that, if the module is not enabled. Maybe it is, but the above solution did not worked. Now i can not test it because all my pages are redirected with the other way (meta tags).

Comment: Sure, all fine. In the end all you are interested in is that the requests get redirected. I just tried to express my surprise, that's all. Have fun!